# ¿Cómo usar .reduce con una función externa?

Tags: javascript, function

Tengo una pregunta relacionada con la función .reduce. Estoy refactorizando un código antiguo y, para cumplir con el principio DRY, me gustaría saber cómo crear una función que me permita lograr el siguiente proceso:

- Agrupe los datos por una determinada clave (`phoNumbId` en el ejemplo).
- Suma los valores de otra clave (relacionada con la primera
  clave) para resumir ambas (esta clave es `mount`).
- Devolver un diccionario con la clave agrupada y los valores agregados

Para aclarar mi pregunta, tengo este diccionario de ejemplo:

```
const nexus = [
  { namesId: 1, phoNumbId: 1, country: 'PERU', mount: 1200 },
  { namesId: 1, phoNumbId: 2, country: 'CANADA', mount: 2000},
  { namesId: 2, phoNumbId: 2, country: 'ENGLAND', mount: 3000},
  { namesId: 2, phoNumbId: 3, country: 'RUSSIA', mount: 40000},
  { namesId: 3, phoNumbId: 1, country: 'BELGIUM', mount: 500},
  { namesId: 3, phoNumbId: 2, country: 'SPAIN', mount: 500},
  { namesId: 3, phoNumbId: 3, country: 'PORTUGAL', mount: 2020}
]
```

Y el código que quiero refactorizar es:

```
var result2 = [];

    nexus.reduce(function (res, value) {
            if (!res[value.phoNumbId]) {
                res[value.phoNumbId] = { phoNumbId: value.phoNumbId, mount: 0 };
                result2.push(res[value.phoNumbId])
            }
            res[value.phoNumbId].mount+= value.mount;
            return res;
        }, {});
```

La forma en que mi conocimiento limitado en JS me permite codificar una posible solución es la siguiente:

```
function sumAll(firstValue,secondValue,finalArray){
 if (!res[value.firstValue]) {
            res[value.firstValue] = { firstValue: value.firstValue, secondValue: 0 };
            finalArray.push(res[value.firstValue])
        }
        res[value.primerValor].secondValue+= value.secondValue;
        return res;
}

var result2 = [];

nexus.reduce(function (res, value) { sumAll(phoNumbId,mount,result2) }, {});
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda y/o explicación

Comment: No termino de entender la idea: ¿Podrías contarnos qué es lo que quieres conseguir con tus propias palabras? Y quizá crear un ejemplo de resultado que quieres obtener

Comment: @PabloLozano Si, por supuesto. En el script utilizo muchas veces la función reduce, y a fin de no repetir las mismas líneas de código una y otra vez, quisiera crear una función que simplifique el proceso. Editaré la pregunta, a ver si la clarifico.

Comment: @PabloLozano No se cómo ni por qué, pero me acabo de iluminar y se me ocurrió como poder resolverlo jaja. Disculpa los inconvenientes. Si logro resolverlo cerraré la pregunta.

Comment: Mejor aún: Puedes poner tú una respuesta a tu pregunta y marcarla como aceptada. Puede ayudar a iluminar a otros o podemos revisar si es la mejor manera de resolver tu escenario :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Luego de consultar en otro foro, y en base a las respuestas de @Andy y @Khoa, [aquí esta la solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74795094/refactor-how-to-use-reduce-with-an-external-function)

En dicho enlace, se entrega el siguiente código que cumple con lo consultado en la pregunta:

```
const data=[{namesId:1,phoNumbId:1,country:"PERU",mount:1200},{namesId:1,phoNumbId:2,country:"CANADA",mount:2e3},{namesId:2,phoNumbId:2,country:"ENGLAND",mount:3e3},{namesId:2,phoNumbId:3,country:"RUSSIA",mount:4e4},{namesId:3,phoNumbId:1,country:"BELGIUM",mount:500},{namesId:3,phoNumbId:2,country:"SPAIN",mount:500},{namesId:3,phoNumbId:3,country:"PORTUGAL",mount:2020}];

function sumAll(data, first, second) {

  const temp = data.reduce((acc, c) => {
    
    const key = c[first];
    
    acc[key] ??= { [first]: key, [second]: 0 };
    
    return acc;
  
  }, {});
  
  return Object.values(temp);
  
}

console.log(sumAll(data, 'phoNumbId', 'mount'));
console.log(sumAll(data, 'namesId', 'mount'));
```

Comment: Podrias hacer un resumen o analisis de como pudiste resolverlo, tu respuesta es de muy baja calidad debido a que 1- Solo muestra un enlace y ningun otro antecedente, si el enlace muere tu respuesta pierde el poco sentido que tiene. 2- Estamos en SO español, y tu enlace redirige al sitio en inglés, muchas personas irán a la respuesta y no entenderán que dice, por eso es valioso que resumas como pudiste resolverlo detalladamente para otras personas que tengan el mismo problema a futuro.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/368458)

Comment: Ningún problema, me parece del todo razonable que indiquen eso @padaleiana. Lo siento por lo escueta de la respuesta, me encontraba en horario laboral. Ahora edito la pregunta principal explicando de mejor manera mi duda y linkeando una posible solución. Gracias por su feedback!

Comment: El comentario que dejé es uno por defecto que se asigna en las colas de revisión (es más, pulsá en el enlace de "Desde revisión" para ver la auditoría de la respuesta). Ten siempre presente que esta es la zona de respuestas: no coloques en tu pregunta lo que hiciste para resolver tu problema. El formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Edita esta respuesta (o bórrala) y redacta una nueva escribiendo lo que te sirvió (que probablemente fue lo que colocaste erróneamente en la pregunta). Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.