# En Python, es posible solo almacenar los numeros primos en una lista?

Tags: python

**Hago uso de esta funcion, pero me percate que tambien se guardan los números compuestos **

```
def primo(numero):
num1=numero//2
if numero == 0 or numero == 1 or numero == 4:
    return False
for x in range(num1, int(numero/2)):
    if numero % x == 0:
        return False
return True
NumerosP=[]
for i in range(100000,101000):
if primo(i):
        NumerosP.append(i)
print(NumerosP)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la programación, donde un 10% es escribir código y un 90% debugear

Comment: Entiendo el problema pero el código no tanto. La identación en Python no es un capricho, es una necesidad impuesta por el lenguaje para identificar a qué contexto pertenece una instrucción. Mejora eso por favor.

Comment: ademas de la indentación el problema estaría en `for x in range(num1, int(numero/2)):`  estás haciendo que el for no recorra el "rango" y devuelve siempre true, `print(numero, num1, int(numero/2))` antes del for te da pistas de pq el "rango" no se recorre, un `print(x)` dentro del for nunca se ejecuta ( por consiguiente nunca llega al if q daria false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teodoro.

Entiendo tu intención con las líneas 2:4 de tu condigo, sin embargo sobran, te dejo acá una función básica para lo que buscas:

```
def primo(n):
 for i in range(2,n):
  if (n%i) == 0:
   return False
return True
```

Exitos

Fuente: https://geekflare.com/es/prime-number-in-python/

Comment: Si bien un enlace puede ser útil, la respuesta debe explicarse por si misma. Hubiera sido mejor dejarle un comentario antes que una respuesta. Aún no tienes el privilegio, pero eso no te habilita a usar las respuestas como si fueran comentarios si esa era tu intención.

Comment: ¿Opinas que mi respuesta es insuficiente? escribí lo que yo creo que él busca, puedes leerlo en el fragmento de mi respuesta: ** "te dejo acá una función básica para lo que buscas:" ** . Aun si tuviera el privilegio; se me es imposible anexar código en un comentario.

Comment: Me refiero a que deberías explicar un poco tu código o qué está mal con el suyo y cómo lo puede arreglar.

Comment: Que la respuesta consista de poco más que un enlace es una razón por la que puede ser cerrada. Está en los [mensajes predeterminados de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/573353/c%C3%B3mo-usar-reduce-con-una-funci%C3%B3n-externa#comment1014566_573758). Simplemente queremos que les vaya bien en el sitio y por eso nos tomamos la molestia de dejar este tipo de comentarios.

Comment: No le explicaste donde tenía el error.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

El error está en

```
for x in range(num1, int(numero/2)):
```

pues `num1` vale `numero//2`. O sea, no tienes rango para iterar.

Lo correcto es hacer el ciclo desde el valor 2, así:

```
for x in range(2, int(numero/2)):
```

#### Demo

```
def primo(numero):
    num1=numero//2

    if numero == 0 or numero == 1 or numero == 4:
        return False

    for x in range(2, int(numero/2)):
        if numero % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
NumerosP=[]

for i in range(100000,101000):
    if primo(i):
            NumerosP.append(i)
print(NumerosP)

[100003, 100019, 100043, 100049, 100057, 100069, 100103, 100109, 100129, 100151, 100153, 100169, 100183, 100189, 100193, 100207, 100213, 100237, 100267, 100271, 100279, 100291, 100297, 100313, 100333, 100343, 100357, 100361, 100363, 100379, 100391, 100393, 100403, 100411, 100417, 100447, 100459, 100469, 100483, 100493, 100501, 100511, 100517, 100519, 100523, 100537, 100547, 100549, 100559, 100591, 100609, 100613, 100621, 100649, 100669, 100673, 100693, 100699, 100703, 100733, 100741, 100747, 100769, 100787, 100799, 100801, 100811, 100823, 100829, 100847, 100853, 100907, 100913, 100927, 100931, 100937, 100943, 100957, 100981, 100987, 100999]

Process finished with exit code 0
```